# NServiceBus 4.0 -- Could Not Determine message type from message header

Tags: nservicebus

I'm working my way through the PluralSight training demo on NSB.

I've refactored the solution into a Service orientated solution, but when I run the backend project, and submit an order, I receive the following:

> 2013-09-20 11:49:59,712 [15] WARN 
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.DefaultDispatcherFactory [(null)] <(null)> - Could
>   not determine message type from message header 'BusSto
>   p.Sales.InternalMessages.PlaceOrder, BusStop.Sales.InternalMessages,
>   Version=1.0 .0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. MessageId:
>   4984ecad-2ae1-423b-8f29- a23f00c30008

My message is defined as:

```
using System;
using NServiceBus;

namespace BusStop.Sales.InternalMessages
{
    public class PlaceOrder : IMessage
    {
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How do I help NSB resolve the message type?

Comment: Nevermind.. I discovered the backend solution didn't have a reference to the internalmessages assembly.

Comment: You should add this as an answer then accept it.